# Check user membership of current user in security group using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-on-prem

I am working on SharePoint 2016 on-premises environment. I need to implement the some functionality based on the result whether the currently logged-in user is a part of a security group or not using javascript/jquery. Can someone advise on how I can check the user membership in a security group?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPServices to check the Current User. Here is an example

```
var userInGroup=false;
var site = "/sites/Sitename";

  $().SPServices({
  operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
  userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
                           webURL: site
                       }),
  webURL: site,
  async: false,
  completefunc: function (xData, Status){
      if ($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Security Group name']").length == 1){
          userInGroup=true;
      }
  }
  });

  if(userInGroup)
  {
  $("input[title='Priority Confirmed']").closest("tr").show();

  }
  else
  {
  $("input[title='Priority Confirmed']").closest("tr").hide();
  } 
});
```

Here is an article for reference [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: Hello @rrr : thanks for your response. Well, I tried to implement the solution provided by you, but it does not work for me. To be on the same page, I want to clarify that here by security group I am referring to the distribution list that has been converted to security group to make it detectable in SharePoint environment. Any other suggestions?